# Keep duplicate data in matrix visual Power BI

Tags: database, matrix, powerbi, powerquery, calculated-columns

I'm facing an issue and hope you'll be able to help me.

I have a matrix with a lot of data and I've noticed that if a line have two same rows, Power BI brings them together immediately and sum the numbers.

Do you think that it's possible to tell Power BI do not summarize any row of the matrix?

Thank you.

Sample Screenshot:
[image: See the image below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Power BI Matrix* behaves similarly to the *Excel Pivot Table*, in which the aggregated data in the *Values area* is filtered by *rows* and *columns*: **Double filter entries make little sense.** However, this can be circumvented with a little workaround.

1. In *PowerQuery* select your table and **add an index column** via `Add Column - Index Column`
2. In the *Power BI* report view add this new index column to the *Rows field* of your matrix

[image: matrix with Index column]

3. In the formatting pane disable `Word wrap` for the *Column headers* and **hide the index column** by pulling the *column width* of the index column with the mouse to **zero**.

[image: matrix with hidden index]

4. You can play around with the position of the index column to what looks best.

But as can be seen, this removes the aggregation in the Values area too.